# Topology of operator bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand the family version of the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem as described in the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson/Michelsohn. In Part III.§8, they define the operator bundle 
$$ Op^m(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F}) \to A $$
as the ''bundle associated to the principal $\mathscr{D}$-bundle of $\mathscr{E} \oplus \mathscr{F} \to A$ by the action of $\mathscr{D}$ on $Op^m(E,F)$''. Here, $\mathscr{E} \oplus \mathscr{F} \to A$ is a continuous pair of vector bundles over some compact manifold $X$ and $\mathscr{D} = \operatorname{Diff}(E,F;X)$. The space $A$ is a compact Hausdorff parameter space.

1. What is the ''principal bundle of $\mathscr{E} \oplus \mathscr{F}$''?
2. How is $Op^m(E,F)$ topologized?
3. What is a good reference for the theory of continuous fibre bundles (which are not necessarily principal $G$-bundles for some Lie group $G$),  which is implicitely used here?

I guess $\mathscr{D}$ is topologized with the $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$-topology and the fibre over some $a$ of $Op^m(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F})$ is (isomorphic to) $Op^m(\mathscr{E}_a, \mathscr{F}_a)$.